# SCEP CertRep SUCCESS: how many certs are in the response?

Tags: x509certificate, certenroll, jscep

I am working on an SCEP implementation (both requester and authority). The project uses JScep as a library.

During the communication for a PKCSReq the client receives a CertRep SUCCESS. The draft says the following:

`+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
   | Request-type   | Reply-contents                                   |
   +----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
   | PKCSReq        | the reply MUST contain at least the issued       |
   |                | certificate in the certificates field of the     |
   |                | Signed-Data.  The reply MAY contain additional   |
   |                | certificates, but the issued certificate MUST be |
   |                | the first in the list.  The reply MUST NOT       |
   |                | contain a CRL.  All returned certificates MUST   |
   |                | conform to [RFC5280].                            |`

I am a bit confused to interpret `MAY contain additional certificates`.

Does this mean that the whole cert chain will be presented in the response as a `Collection` (JScep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole certificate chain may be presented, but not necessarily.  Generally I would expect SCEP servers to provide everything you need to establish a chain of trust.

If you call `enrol` and the resulting `EnrollmentResponse` is successful (`isSuccess()`), you can then call `getCertStore` to access a `java.security.cert.CertStore`.  That `CertStore` will contain all the certificates sent by the server.

You can use the `CertStoreInspector` from jscep to directly extract relevant certificates like so:

```
CertStoreInspector inspector = DefaultCertStoreInspectorFactory.getInstance(certStore);
X509Certificate ca = inspector.getIssuer();
X509Certificate signer_ra = inspector.getSigner();
X509Certificate recipient_ra = inspector.getSigner();
```

See https://github.com/jscep/jscep/issues/48

Comment: Thanks! I suppose the method can be used for receiving a cert chain longer than 2.